# How to understand the PE header in this graph?

Tags: portable-executable

[image]

IMO,this should hold:

```
rva = raw - imagebase
```

which is not the case in the graph,why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The entry point RVA, entry point raw address, and image base address are not related in that way.

The image base is the "preferred address of the first byte of the image when it is loaded in memory".  In other words, it's the virtual address of the image when it gets loaded assuming there's not a conflict.  If there is an address conflict when the image is loaded (e.g. another image is already loaded in an overlapping range), then a new base address will be chosen for the image.

An RVA is a relative virtual address.  It is "relative" in the sense that it is changed when the image is actually loaded.  It's the address when the base address is not known (e.g. when the image isn't loaded).  Once the image is loaded, the RVA becomes a virtual address (VA), an actual address in virtual memory.

The raw vs. RVA distinction is due to alignment.  There is section alignment (the alignment of the sections when they get loaded into memory) as well as file alignment (the alignment of the raw data in the sections).  The section alignment here is 0x1000 while the file alignment is 0x200.

The entry point RVA is used to determine the VA of the entry point when the image is loaded (i.e. the entry point will be located at virtual address `EntryPoint (rva) + ImageBase`).  The entry point raw address is the offset into the file where the entry point is located.

[This document](http://webster.cs.ucr.edu/Page_TechDocs/pe.txt) has a good explanation of alignment.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean by `offset into the file where the entry point is located`,can you elaborate it?

Comment: I might be incorrect, but my understanding is that the entry point has an address in memory when loaded (RVA + image base), and an "address" on disk when the image is not loaded.  The "address" on disk is really just the offset into the file.  So, if you wanted to start disassembling the entry point without having to first load the image, you would seek to the raw entry point address in the file.

Comment: The `EntryPoint (rva)` should be calculated based on `EntryPoint (raw)` during image loading ,is that right?

Comment: The entry point at runtime will be at `Entry Point (rva) + ImageBase` (the image base address can change from the default specified in the DLL if there is a load conflict due to another DLL already being loaded at that address).